# Can't see my app's Internal Storage using File Explorer

Tags: android, android-studio, internal-storage, scoped-storage

I've successfully saved an image into my App's internal storage which I can get the path to and also load that image into an image view.

However I'm trying to view that file using Android Studio's file explorer, but I'm unable to see my package appearing inside the device File Explorer.

[image]

I've tried using the **synchronize** option after saving my image, but my package is still not appearing in the internal storage.

[image]

Why is the package for my app not appearing?

```
private void loadFileUsingScopedStorage(String url, final String fileName){
        File[] files = getFilesDir().listFiles(new FileFilter() {
            @Override
            public boolean accept(File file) {
                return file.canRead() && file.isFile() && file.getName().equals(fileName);
            }
        });
        if(files != null){
            if(files.length == 0){
                Log.d(TAG, "loadFileUsingScopedStorage: Not found, downloading and saving");
                saveFileUsingScopedStorage(url, fileName);
            }else{
                Log.d(TAG, "loadFileUsingScopedStorage: " + Arrays.toString(files));
                loadImageWithGlide(imageView, files[0].toString());
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I was looking at the wrong directory. The correct directory for the internal storage path is ```data/data/com.dave.mycoolapp/files/savedpicture.jpg```

Comment: If you use `filesDir` then it is under `data/data/...`, & under `Android/data/...` if using `externalFilesDir`

Comment: Didn't know about the external files one. Thanks for the tip.